# Create copy of active workbook. Then return to master copy to complete. Cannot copy sheets with table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that generates a copy of an excel under a new name while not overriding the original. It is used to generate a copy for all staff while protecting the original.

I am trying to create a similar file that saves a copy of the visible sheets with todays date in another sharepoint location, but my macro hits an error because the sheets I am copying contain tables.

Exact error: "cannot copy sheet that contains table" the macro fails on line "Sheets(myArray).Copy" any ideas would be greatly appreciated :-)

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = 0
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Visible = True Then
        ReDim Preserve myArray(j)
        myArray(j) = i
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Sheets(myArray).Select
Sheets(myArray).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Low Level" & newdate & ".xlsx", 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, according to [this article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/08/31/copying-worksheets-with-a-list-or-table/) the limitation is only that you cannot copy *multiple* sheets with tables at the same time using `Sheets(..).Copy`.

That is, you can copy one sheet with a table at a time with `Sheets(..).Copy` or alternatively, you can copy multiple sheets with tables using some other methods such as `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy`.

(I have not tested this, so you will have to confirm for yourself)

Comment: That is a helpful article. Thanks. I am still having some trouble with it, but I think I have figured a work around. Thanks